# What is the info-thingy before the CLI cursor called?

Tags: command-line, shell, terminology

So, in all command lines I've ever seen, there's a little info-thingy at the start of the line before the cursor.

CMD just shows your current working directory:

[image: CMD]

PowerShell does the same and also reminds you that you're using PowerShell:

[image: PowerShell]

Bash on Ubuntu also displays your hostname and username so you don't get confused with SSH:

[image: Bash on Ubuntu]

And ZSH can go even further with info about source control, return code, time and whatever you want really.

[image]

*But what is it called?*

In the sentence, "I have to print a newline at the end of this script so the **info-thingy** is displayed properly.", what would be the correct term for **info-thingy**?

Comment: It is just different presentations for different operating systems and tools.  They are not supposed to be the same.  Make sure in Windows that you need Powershell. Useful as it is, I changed the Windows 10 Default to the more basic Command Processor which is better for small tasks.

Comment: I guess it's called a form of 'notation'

Comment: @John I understand that they're supposed to be different, my question is what they are called. What is the correct term to refer to this thing?

Comment: It is normally just called "Greater than" symbol and has been used by convention by Microsoft since day 1 (DOS)

Comment: @John dear god.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called "**prompt**". Yeah, that's all.

For example, many people like to customize them:

[How to change the prompt in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35777/388654)

[PowerShell: How to customize prompt?](https://serverfault.com/q/146354)

Comment: And `cmd` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/prompt